# Hadoop - Can name node execute task?

Tags: hadoop, namenode

Is it possible for the name node to execute tasks? By default, the tasks execute on the data nodes of the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are asking about MapReduce...

With YARN, MapReduce tasks execute in application masters, not namenodes and not within the datanode process. These are monitored by the ResourceManager.

Application master services are only commonly installed along side the datanode, and you can install it on the namenode as well, but you really shouldn't in a production environment